# css Hold animation after it finish

Tags: css

For example I make scale from 1 to 2, and I want to make it hold when it gets to scale 2, for example while the user hovers some image it is scaled, is that possible?

```
@-webkit-keyframes scale {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    }
}
@keyframes scale {
    from {
        transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Safari and Chrome */
    }
    to {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
    }
}

div.item:hover
{
animation: scale 2s;
-webkit-animation: scale 2s;
}
```

Comment: No need to put `-ms-transform` into `@-webkit-keyframes`.

Answer (score 3):

use `animation-fill-mode`: `forwards` or `both`

```
div.item:hover
{
animation: scale 2s forwards;
-webkit-animation: scale 2s forwards;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the transition property instead of the keyframes animation.

```
div.item {
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: all .2s;
}

div.item:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8eHHL/

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
.div.item { animation: bubble 1.0s forwards;
   -webkit-animation: bubble 1.0s forwards;  /* for other modern browsers */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.I think it will work.
I give only webkit(Crome) version you need to write for all.

```
@-webkit-keyframes scale{
     0% {
        transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(1); /* Safari and Chrome */
     }
     100% {
        transform: scale(1.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari and Chrome */
     }
    }

div.item:hover
{
  -webkit-animation: scale 2s;
}
```

Comment: i don't see any difference, from is equal to 0, and to is equal to 100%, the animation resets after it finish...

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's impossible to keep result of animation in your case. You bind animation on hover and trying to keep it when user blurs mouse from your element. But there is ability to keep animaton on click. [click event is done with :target](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3Lightbox/index2.html#page)